# How to change width/height of imported object in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am using Three.js for my project and currently I am importing .OBJ file with OBJ LOADER (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj)

Everything is working great so far, but now I hit a problem that I don't know how to solve.
I need to change width and height of my imported object via dom controls. For example, currently I have a bed model and I want to change the width of this bed interactively. Is this even possible? Because I am in problems if it's not :)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada.html

In this example they scale their object with

item.scale.x = item.scale.y = item.scale.z = 0.002;

Comment: Ryan thank you. I tried and it works. Any idea how could I actually get the total width of an object ? Is there any method to determine total width of object?

Comment: Nope I am Also a noobie at THREE.js :)